# Requirejs-rails only working in debug mode

Tags: requirejs-rails

I have created a small project with rails and added the requirejs-rails gem. I have set it up as required and while running assets:precompile, it fails when requirejs-rails tries to compile the javascript resources. However, oddly enough, the assets:precompile seems to work when in debug mode. Unfortunately, I need it to run in non-debug mode so it can be properly deployed on Heroku. Below is the error and stack trace. Any one encountered this? More importantly, any solution to this?

`/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/whyves/RubymineProjects/test2/bin/spring rake --trace assets:precompile
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:external (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:test_node (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:test_node
** Execute requirejs:precompile:external
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby rake --trace assets:precompile requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- rake --trace assets:precompile (LoadError)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ru...]
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in`block in create_shell_runner'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in`sh'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in`ruby'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.3/lib/tasks/requirejs-rails_tasks.rake:19:in`ruby_rake_task'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.3/lib/tasks/requirejs-rails_tasks.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`call'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`each'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in`each'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in`invoke_task'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
/home/whyves/RubymineProjects/test2/bin/rake:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`load'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
/home/whyves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
/home/whyves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in`'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => requirejs:precompile:external

Process finished with exit code 1

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, it is not with rails or requirejs-rails. The problem lies with my IDE (RubyMine). When I precompile from a command window, it works but when I launch the task from RubyMine, it fails!